# Explicitly formatting field value as text

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, reporting-services

I have some fields containing hierarchic numberings such as “1.2”, “1.2.1”, “1.2.1.3”.

If I create a report to Excel, Excel thinks that values with only one point may be a numeric type and shows the green arrow above of the value.
Is there a possibility to define a custom format for the concerned TextBox, so that Excel knows that the contained value should be treated as text?

I have already searched the web and also tried some workarounds I had myself, such as adding a space after the last character, but I was unable to find a working solution.

Comment: what version of reportviewer? (2005 or 2008/2010)

Comment: you mention custom formats, presuming you've tried right clicking the TextBoxes and setting the format as text?

Comment: @Phil: In the dev-env I dont have the option "Text" (VS2010). There are number-formats, date-formats, time-formats... but no "Text"-format. But may be there is a valid format string for the generic format? I have tried entering "Text" and some simillar values, hovever without success.

Comment: Yes just checking myself, I remember a Text option in 2005. Weird.

Comment: Out of ideas :( Hack'ish workaround could be images?